# Error when Running Built Python App with Py2app

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I'm trying to build an app with Py2app. I'm on Python2.7 and Mac OSX 10.7. The errors occurs on OSX 10.5 as well. The app builds successfully, but when running it in console with the command:

```
rsg.app/Content/MacOS/rsg
I get the following error:
2012-07-05 20:34:56.090 rsg[7483:707] rsg Error
```

Does anyone know what's going on or how we might be able to get some more information, i.e. a stack trace?